# REGEX - PHP Get only bold section in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I am new to Regex. I have a string like:

```
Hello <b>ABCD</b> World
or 
<b>ABCD</b>Hello World
```

I basically want to retain the text inside bold tags but remove all other characters in the string.

I have found the code to remove bold part in the string:

```
$string = 'This is <b>an</b> example <b>text</b>';
echo preg_replace('/(<b>.+?)+(<\/b>)/i', '', $string);
```

So how do I make it to work in opposite way?

Regards
Ahmar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `DOM` parser instead of a regex if you want to extract data from a HTML or XML document. While a regex will work in simple cases too, it can get weird if the use case gets more complicated or the input data changes in an unexpected way. A `DOM` parser is more stable and convenient for that purpose.

Example code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('Hello <b>ABCD</b> World');

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('b') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all("'<b>(.*?)</b>'si", $text, $match);

foreach($match[1] as $val)
{
    echo $val."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
$pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
return $matches[1];
}

$str = 'This is <b>an example text</b>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "b");
print_r($txt);
```

Comment: And what happens if you have 2 same tags on a line?

Comment: $str = "This is <b>an</b> example <b>text</b>"; 
if(preg_match_all("'<b>(.*?)</b>'si",$str,$match)) {            
        foreach($match[1] as $str) 
  {
   $newarray[]=$str;
  }
  print_r($newarray);
}